# error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax( {
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp', 

                url: "https://ss.com/rest/v1/users/demo";
                type: "GET",

                beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("demo" + ":" + "password"));

                },

                 success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("done");
                },
                error: function() {
                   console.log( "not done" );
                }
            } );
```

when i am executing the code in chrome i am getting this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

can anyone help me to get out of this error

Comment: i didn't get u 
when i am executing the above code in chrome i am getting that error

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't have a syntax error, but you've told jQuery that it's a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) request, which means it will cause a `script` element to get added to the document. If that `script` element's `src` points to something that returns [JSON](http://json.org), not JSONP, you'll get that error. The solution is to ensure that you know what the endpoint you're calling *really* provides and either don't specify `dataType` at all, or specify the correct one.

Comment: ok it was json
but when i remove dataType it was throwing this error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: @sailaja.p: That means that the endpoint you're calling doesn't allow cross-origin calls from your origin, so they're being correctly blocked by the browser according to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You'll either have to contact them to ask them to allow you to use their service, or you can't use it from a browser (have to use it from a server or desktop app instead, assuming they don't limit that as well).

Comment: when i am clicking on error link which is in dom level i am getting result but without that i am  not

Comment: @sailaja.p: Right. The SOP applies to ajax requests, not to direct requests. You can have a URL that, when pasted into the browser's address bar, gives you back the data -- but which when used in an ajax request does not. This is specifically so that web pages cannot use (some) resources from *other* web pages without their permission. There's a fundamental difference between going to a page (it's in charge, the URL in the address bar belongs to it, etc.) and *using* that page's resources on your page. Read up on the links I've given you.